# Remove all duplicated IDs from result if one of the IDs contains a specific word

Tags: sql, oracle

Hell all,

i have a Logs tables that shows the workflow of a Task ID i want to display IDs that does not have a specific step.

**The problem:**
the problem i have with using the below query is that the TASK IDs is duplicated and it.

**expected Result:**

remove all Same duplicate Task Id if one of them contains the 'Cart' as STEPNAME

**Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM MV.Tasks 
Where WF_TASK_NAME = 'ExemptionTask'
and stepname not in ('Cart')
```

[image]

Comment: so expected output is to just retain 5408? and delete 5304 and 5321?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT
    *
FROM
    mv.tasks
WHERE
    wf_task_name = 'ExemptionTask'
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            id
        FROM
            mv.tasks
        WHERE
            step_name = 'cart'
    )
```

Comment: it gives no result

Comment: @Alark change wf_task_name = 'ExemptionLoan' for your dataset

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mv.tasks t
where 
    wf_task_name = 'ExemptionTask'
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from mv.tasks t1 
        where t1.id = t.id and t1.wf_task_name = t.wf_task_name and t1.step_name = 'cart'
    )
```

Comment: it gives no result